# Getting error Missing required parameter for [Route: our-board.member] [URI: our-board/member/{boardMember}]

Tags: php, laravel, single-page-application

I have using Laravel 10.x, I have installed Laravel Splade for SPA.

Now, I am getting an error while I am implementing Route Module Binding

[image]

web.php file

```php
Route::group(['prefix' => 'our-board'], function() {
    Route::get('/', [HomeController::class, 'ourBoard'])->name('our-board');
    Route::get('member/{boardMember}', [HomeController::class, 'memberDetail'])->name('our-board.member');
});
```

in Controller

```php
public function ourBoard(): View
{
    $data['boardMembers'] = BoardMember::select([
        'name', 'image'
    ])->get();

    return view('company.our-board', $data);
}

public function memberDetail( BoardMember $boardMember ): View
{
    $data['boardMember'] = $boardMember;
    return view('company.our-board.member', $data);
}
```

In view.

```php
<x-nav-link href="{{ route('our-board.member', ['boardMember' => $boardMember]) }}" class="flex flex-column align-items-center text-decoration-none text-white">
    <div class="card-body text-center">
        <h5 class="card-title m-0">{{ $boardMember->name }}</h5>
    </div>
</x-nav-link>
```

I am missing something? any quick suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Try clearing php artisan cache:clear ,php artisan config:Cache  and then get php artisan route:list so you  can get your route list with expected parameters

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: Your code looks good, Check if `$boardMember` has some value when you use it in the view

Comment: Yes, I found the issue. I forgot to add `id` in the select. :(

Answer (score -1):

I have not added `id` in the selection.

```php
$data['boardMembers'] = BoardMember::select([
    'id', 'name', 'image'
])->get();
```

If we do not add `id`, then the modal will bind.